# TLP trouble with udev events. Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: power-management, battery, udev, tlp

My installation of TLP on Ubuntu 19.04 does not automatically change status when charging status changes.

Output from

```
    sudo tlp-stat -s
```

```bsh
    --- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

    +++ System Info
    System         = HP Type1ProductConfigId HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15- cx0xxx
    BIOS           = F.11
    Release        = Ubuntu 19.04
    Kernel         = 5.0.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 09:32:09 UTC 2019 x86_64
    /proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-20-generic root=UUID=60b2ea7a-4132-4a64-8f5c-2e6484bce09a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
    Init system    = systemd v240
    Boot mode      = UEFI

    +++ TLP Status
    State          = enabled
    Last run       = 15:56:31,    795 sec(s) ago
    Mode           = AC
    Power source   = AC
```

Changes to:

```bsh
    --- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

    +++ System Info
    System         = HP Type1ProductConfigId HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-cx0xxx
    BIOS           = F.11
    Release        = Ubuntu 19.04
    Kernel         = 5.0.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 09:32:09 UTC 2019 x86_64
    /proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-20-generic root=UUID=60b2ea7a-4132-4a64-8f5c-2e6484bce09a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
    Init system    = systemd v240
    Boot mode      = UEFI

    +++ TLP Status
    State          = enabled
    Last run       = 15:56:31,    916 sec(s) ago
    Mode           = AC
    Power source   = battery
```

When unplugging the power cable.
Since TLP uses udev events (as far as I understand) the first step I did was to check if events are correctly recieved.

```bsh
    sudo udevadm monitor
    monitor will print the received events for:
    UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
    KERNEL - the kernel uevent
```

I unplugged the cable a few times and saw the charging status on the laptop change but nothing being printed in the console running the above monitor.

Also note that I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 19.04. It did however not work even before the upgrade.

Any ideas? I am at my wits end when it comes to this.

Comment: That is the output from tlp stat -s

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an older version of `tlp` on Ubuntu 16.04 where `udevadm` is working properly. The rules are stored here:

```
$ ll /lib/udev/rules.d/*tlp*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1221 Aug 11  2015 /lib/udev/rules.d/85-tlp-rdw.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  440 Aug 11  2015 /lib/udev/rules.d/85-tlp.rules
```

There have been recent bug reports of your situation:

- [AC not detect when plugged in](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/375)
- [AC mode not detected with USB charger](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/320)

All bugs were reported on your TLP version `1.1` and fixes were released under version `1.2`.

See the bug reports for instructions to fix.

Comment: Those links didn't seem to fix it but i might have found the cause. /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status is showing as Unknown instead of Charging or Discharging which should(?) be expected. Is this some issue with the battery or maybe the laptop itself?  I also tried running version 1.3 from the creators git with the same results

Comment: Mine shows `Full`. Maybe try: `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status` instead?

Comment: My battery shows up as `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` instead of `BAT0`. `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status` does however show up correctly as charging or discharging. Do you think there is a way to change the udev event to listen to `BAT1` instead of `BAT0` or to maybe change the TLP rules to accomodate this difference? Sorry if the questions are basic, still pretty new to this.